# What's to think of when increasing disk size on Cassandra nodes?

Tags: cassandra

I run a 10-node Cassandra cluster in production. 99% writes; 1% reads, 0% deletes. The nodes have 32 GB RAM; C* runs with 8 GB heap. Each node has a SDD for commitlog and 2x4 TB spinning disks for data (sstables). The schema uses key caching only. C* version is 2.1.2.

It can be predicted that the cluster will run out of free disk space in not too long. So its storage capacity needs to be increased. The client prefers increasing disk size over adding more nodes. So a plan is to take the 2x4 TB spinning disks in each node and replace by 3x6 TB spinning disks.

- Are there any obvious pitfalls/caveats to be aware of here? Like:

  - Can C* handle up to 18 TB data size per node with this amount of RAM?
  - Is it feasible to increase the disk size by mounting a new (larger) disk, copy all SS tables to it, and then mount it on the same mount point as the original (smaller) disk (to replace it)?

Comment: You perhaps won't have to move data. In `cassandra.yaml` the parameter `data_file_directories` can have multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend adding nodes instead of increasing the data size of your current nodes. Adding nodes would take advantage of Cassandra's distribution feature by having small easily replaceable nodes.

Furthermore the recommended size of a single node in a cluster for a spinning disk is around 1 TB. Once you go higher than that, I can only image that performance will decrease significantly.

Not to mention if a node loses its data, it will take a long time to recover it as it has to stream a huge amount of data from the other nodes.

> Can C* handle up to 18 TB data size per node with this amount of RAM?

This depends heavily on your workload.

> Is it feasible to increase the disk size by mounting a new (larger) disk, copy all SS tables to it, and then mount it on the same mount point as the original (smaller) disk (to replace it)?

I don't see a reason why it would not work.

Comment: Thank you for this advice. Given the OP, I will attempt to equip the existing nodes with larger disks. If this proves a bad idea; I will use the old disks in new nodes to be added. But since I have very few reads, performance might be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

It's an anti-pattern in Cassandra. Distributed database is key feature of Cassandra